# How to extract an excerpt from the content variable?

Tags: python, django, string, search

I'm doing a search for hierarchical dictionary, and I have to put the content into a variable named "content":

```
def look_through(d, s):
    r = []
    content = readFile(d["path"])

    if s in content:
        if "phrase" not in d:
            d["phrase"] = [s]
        else:
            d["phrase"].append(s)
        r.append({"content": content, "phrase": d["phrase"], "name": d["name"]})
    for b in d["decendent"] or []:
            r += look_through(b, s)
    return r
```

But the "content" should be an exceprt from the text, not the full content, i.e. several words from behind and several words in front of the searching phrase.

E.g.:

phrase: "**looking for**"

content: ... she was **looking for** him...

How to crop the content in a function in order to achieve this result?
Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that all you know is that `s in content`—in other words, you know the string is in there *somewhere*, but you need to know *where* to get the context.

Just use [`content.find(s)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) instead, and you'll have that:

```
pos = content.find(s)
if pos != -1:
    if "phrase" not in d:
        # etc.
```

Now, to find "several words behind", just search backward for several word separators from `pos`, and to find "a couple words ahead", search forward for several word separators from `pos + len(s)`.

Of course you have to define what "several" means, and what constitutes a word separator, but you should be able to work out the rest from here. (Make sure you see `rfind` along with `find` in the docs, and look at all of the parameters to both methods, and don't forget to handle the edge case where `s` is found right near the start or end of `content`.)

One last side note: Are you sure that `s in content` (and, equivalently, `content.find(s)`) is really what you want? For example, if I search for "sing out", should that be found in "The star is losing outer layers"?

Comment: The problem is that in my case the needed word can be found several times in one content also. So I have to look for several matchings of the word.

Comment: @paus: That's fine. Look at the other arguments to `find` and it should be obvious how to look for additional matches.

Comment: And I'm not sure, that "pos = content.find(s)" is a proper solution for my case because words can change their form so I need to use something like pymorphy2 in combination with find() function.

Comment: @paus: OK, if you need something that wasn't in your original question, but you know what you need, that shouldn't be a problem. (If you get stuck trying to implement it, you've got a new question.)